The Definition of a Vector Bundle/$G$-Equivariant Vector Bundle over a $G$-set
Let $G$ be a profinite group. (I don't believe this is necessary, but this is the context I am reading this in) and let $X$ be a finite discrete $G$-set. In chapter 1.5 exercise 8 of Cohomology of Number Fields, the authors define a vector bundle over $X$.

A complex vector bundle on $X$ is a continuous representation $G\to GL(\mathcal{V})$ on a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\mathcal{V}$ such that the projection $X\times \mathcal{V}\to X$ is a morphism of $G$-sets.

I am trying to understand why the last condition (that $X\times \mathcal{V}\to X$ is a morphism of $G$-sets) is not tautological. Let $X$ and $\mathcal{V}$ be arbitrary, and let $\pi:X\times \mathcal{V}\to X$ be the set-theoretic projection. Then we have
$$\pi(g(x,v))=\pi((gx,gv))=gx=g\pi((x,v))$$
so $\pi$ is always a morphism of $G$ sets. However, I must have made a mistake because this means that a vector bundle on $X$ is just a continuous, finite-dimensional complex representation of $G$.
Given the rest of the exercise, I believe that the information of an isomorphism class of a $1$-dimensional vector bundle on $X=G/H$ for an open subgroup $H\subseteq G$ should be equivalent to a $1$-dimensional representation of $H$.

This is incorrectly named. The object being defined here should be called a $G$-equivariant vector bundle on $X$.

I've added G-equivariant vector bundle to the title, but I've also left in just "vector bundle" as that is the language my textbook uses, so future readers of the book can find this question.

Seems to me in this definition that $\mathcal{V}$ has nothing to do with $X$. Is that really the case? I would expect the bundle $\pi:[\text{something}]\to X$ to not be the trivial one!

I'm answering my own question with what I believe the answer to be after talking to my local equivariant topologist. As Qiaochu Yuan mentioned in the comments, the object the book defines is more often referred to as a $G$-equivariant vector bundle.
This is quite strange as the definition does not look much like the one given in the book, but here is what I believe the book intended to define:
A $G$-equivariant bundle on $X$ is a topological vector bundle $\pi:E\to X$ on the discrete space $X$ such that $E$ has a $G$ action, and $\pi$ is $G$-equivariant.
Using this definition, we do get the expected result that the information of a vector bundle on $X=G/H$ is equivalent to a representation of $H$. If $\pi:E\to X$ is a vector bundle, then for any $x\in X$ the stabalizer subgroup of $x$, which is exactly $H$, should act on the vector space $\pi^{-1}\{x\}$.
Moreover, for any representation of $H$ you can construct a vector bundle on $X$. Fix coset representatives $g_i$ of $G/H$. For a representation $H\to \text{GL}(\mathcal{V})$ and then define $E=X\times \mathcal{V}$ with the action of $g=g_i h$ given by $g_ih(x,v)=(g_ix, hv)$.
